Log into SharePoint online through C# and using Office Dev PnP Core
I have a console application in which I am logging into SharePoint using code below.
try
 {
     var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
     using (var clientContext = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext("https://xyz.sharepoint.com/"))
     {
         clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web.CurrentUser);
         clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
         Console.WriteLine(clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.Title);
         clientContext.RequestTimeout = -1;
     }
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
     throw ex;
 }

GetWebLoginClientContext method prompts for Authentication but within seconds, it just disappears and takes the cookie for my regular user.
I want to switch to another user but authManager takes and uses the existing cache, which causes it to log in with the existing account.
I have already tried the below things to solve the issue but none of it is working.

Clear Internet Options.
Clear Edge Cache.
Delete all browser profiles.
After deleting all types of cache, restart the system

But still, it takes the default user's credentials.
I want GetWebLoginClientContext to stay open enough to enter the user's credentials.
Is there any way where we can forcefully clear the cache or any other way, to make the authentication prompt appear every time the application runs?
I see the same question was asked 4 years ago but still does not have the answer to it.
Log into SharePoint tenant through CSOM with MFA enabled
Any help would be really appreciated as this issue has caused a blocker for us in Production.

You could roll back the .net framework version before 4.6 to use pnp core library.
